# FTP many images from one server to another server in fastest way

Tags: images, ftp, transfer

I have many images in my server and I want transfer my data to another server.

I want combine those files to one file and then FTP. I am using 7-zip with "store" option to make one file, but it is very slow.

Is there any fast solution?

Comment: Are these servers local to each other? or connected via the net?

Comment: Both servers are online web servers, but i think it is not important

Comment: Are you looking for the fastest overall solution or the fastest for you solution? Fastest overall would be what you are doing, the fastest for you would just be to go to your new server and download everything (ignoring the fact that you're wasting a little bandwidth to be so lazy).

Answer (score 3):

If you can open access via ssh between your servers, then using `rysnc` to transfer the data would be much faster than ftp.  Rsync automatically transfers data in batches and if you have to run the transfer multiple times, it only has to transfer the data that has changed.

Unfortunately, [rsync does not work over ftp but this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp) suggests that some ftp clients do rsync like "mirror" checks for the case that you have to keep two directories in sync:

> lftp and ncftp both have "mirror" modes that will probably meet your needs.
>
> I use this to push stuff from my local directory to a ftp or sftp web host:
>
> ```
> lftp -c "set ftp:list-options -a;
> open ftp://user:password@your.ftp.com; 
> lcd ./web;
> cd /web/public_html;
> mirror --reverse --delete --use-cache --verbose --allow-chown --allow-suid --no-umask --parallel=2 --exclude-glob .svn"
> ```